# New Lego Star Wars Character Encyclopedia

Tags: star-wars

I am wondering when the newest version of the Lego Stars Wars Character Encyclopedia will be released?   The latest version is from 2015, I believe, and does not incorporate the new movies.

I would greatly appreciate any information you have on release date.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to Bricks! We're not actually part of The LEGO Group and don't have advance details of when new products are released - indeed as a Recognised LEGO Online Community we are not allowed to re-publish leaked details